# Word usage 'when you go'

Tags: word-usage

Is there any thing wrong in the following sentence:

> Could you please inform me **when you go**.

Can I use 'when you go' like this?

Comment: It makes perfect sense 100%.  It does sound a little informal. It's exactly how people speak.  In writing, you'd probably add more fat: "Could you please let me know, when you leave the house?"  "When you get in the car to go to the airport, please pick up the phone and let me know you are leaving."

Comment: @Joe Blow: I'm intrigued. When you say it *sounds a little informal*, is that on account of the "when you go" part? Curiously enough, I find the word "inform" sounds formal, rather than informal!

Comment: @Fumb, I agree 100% with what you said.  "When you go" is a bit loose an informal.  Yes, "inform" is formal.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to express, so I won't stand against your sentence, but the only possible meaning I can come up with right now would be expressed by:

> Could you please inform me when you leave?

If that doesn't fit where you need it to, please, provide more info on the context.

**EDIT:** To make sure I'm not mistaken, I googled both phrases and now I'm even more confident.

*When you go* is always followed by a certain place or action, like:

> When you go online.
>   When you go to Brazil.

While *when you leave* simply stands by itself:

> If you decide not to go on with this course, please come and inform me when you leave.

Of course, optionally you can add some place after *leave*, like:

> Give me a call when you leave the office, so that I can prepare the food in time.

But this isn't necessary for the word to work.

Comment: @RiMMER, I was just wondering, when is "leave" used, and when is "go" used, and what is the difference?

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: Again, I'm not claiming the original sentence is wrong, I just couldn't find any situation where it would fit. "When you go" seems either informal or incomplete to me. Go where? To the bathroom? To the window? "When you leave" doesn't ask for anything else in my opinion. "When you leave whatever place you currently reside in."

Comment: "go away" maybe?

Comment: Made it a question @RiMMER

Comment: Exactly as you said: "go away" = "leave". "Leave" stands by itself, "go" requires additional "info". Am I wrong?

Comment: @Rimmer: not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is grammatically correct.  In speaking, it would be more common to hear:

> Could you please let me know when you go?

Because we don't use the word "inform" all that often when we talk.

But in writing, I agree with @RiMMER that "leave" would be a better way to express the concept you're trying to get across.  Likewise "would" instead of "could", because you're not really asking whether they *can* let you know. And "please" is not too often used in writing either:

> Would you let me know when you leave?

Comment: Voting up, definitely. The "would" vs "could" difference seems a little strict, but I get the point.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough context to answer definitively. **...when you go** can be grammatically acceptable without being followed by anything, but in *most* situations, **...when you leave** is the preferred form.

To my ear, **...when you go** is 'more' okay if the word **go** has recently been used *and/or* a destination has been named...

"We're going down the pub later. Do you want to come?"

"No thanks, but let me know when you go"