# "Leave" vs. "Go"

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs

From [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/32744/8183), I was just wondering, what is the difference between "leave" and "go" in terms of the same definition of "departing", and when do we use one, but not the other.
For example, which verb should I use in the following sentence?

> Tell me when you [go/leave].

If it is *leave*, why is it so, and what determines which to use at what time?

I googled this, but there were no discussions or articles on the difference of usage between *leave* and *go*.

Comment: A quick NGram search shows mostly something after "tell me when you go" as in "tell me when you go out" and not after tell me when you leave. Another difference is "Tell me when you go _to_ work" and "Tell me when you leave _for_ work"

Answer (score 2):

You could use either in this instance, but "leave" is the more accurate term of the two: "Go" refers to the *whole* journey whereas "leave" is the act of moving away from the current location - the *beginning* of the journey.

Comment: +1 because you're right that *leaving* focusses on the *act* of moving away from current location. But *going* can be to do with the with just about everything else - including the journey, the destination, or even just the fact that after you *go*, the current location might be empty.

Comment: Very good points. I think what I was trying to get across is that "go" is ambiguous in meaning whereas "leave" is more specific

Comment: Absolutely. OP doesn't give any useful context, but I imagine someone on the security desk at the entrance to an office, where you're effectively being asked to "sign out" when you leave. In which case *leaving* [this building] is the specific matter of interest, not the more general-purpose *going* [somewhere else].

Answer (score 1):

In the example you made, the only difference I see is that *leave* could mean the person is not returning back. One of the meanings of *leave* reported by the NOAD is "depart from permanently."

> She left home when she was 17 years old.

In "I am leaving home at 3:00 p.m. to go first to the doctor, and then to the hospital," *leave* is used in reference to the place I am moving from, and *go* to the place I am moving to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, still in these stock phrases (left school, left home, left his/her job, left his/her husband/wife/lover, etc..) such meaning is more easily and naturally expressed than with 'to go' (or 'to go away').

Comment: @Unreason: I've re-thunk, and will delete my comment. In general **leave** doesn't particularly imply "and not return" to me, but it is much to be preferred over **go** if that meaning *is* required.